# Generate all possible combination with "N" length from given words list (Looking for no repeat)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, backtracking

I would like to generate words sentence with given length. Here i would like to get output without any repeat of characters or words.

With current code i am receiving outputs

```
example example example example example
example example example example example2
example example example example example3
example example example example example4
example example example example example5
example example example example example6
example example example example example7
example example example example example8
example example example example example9
example example example example2 example
example example example example2 example2
```

But i would like to receive output with random words as without any word repeated in sentence

```
example example1 example2 example3 example4
example1 example2 example3 example4 example5
example5 example1 example2 example3 example4
example6 example4 example2 example5 example1
```

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np 
# Python 3 program to print all 
# possible strings of length k 
    
# The method that prints all 
# possible strings of length k. 
# It is mainly a wrapper over 
# recursive function printAllKLengthRec() 
def printAllKLength(set, k): 

    n = len(set) 
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k) 

# The main recursive method 
# to print all possible 
# strings of length k 
def printAllKLengthRec(set, prefix, n, k): 
    
    # Base case: k is 0, 
    # print prefix 
    if (k == 0) : 
        print(prefix) 
        return

    # One by one add all characters 
    # from set and recursively 
    # call for k equals to k-1 
    for i in range(n): 

        # Next character of input added 
        newPrefix = prefix + set[i] 
        
        # k is decreased, because 
        # we have added a new character 
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1) 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    
    
    print("\nSecond Test") 
    set2 = ['example ', 'example2 ', 'example3 ', 'example4 ', 'example5 ', 'example6 ', 'example7 ', 'example8 ', 'example9 '] 
    k = 5
    printAllKLength(set2, k) 

# This code is contributed 
# by ChitraNayal
```

Comment: We aren't doing your homework for you @Kranthi :D , but think sorting and backtracking ! And do it on paper first then code it up!

Comment: Try `itertools.permutations`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: can you explain it better what you want to get in your output

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam Sure mate.

Comment: @codebyAbhishekBharti
I would like to generate with N length of words with no repeat words in sentence

Comment: text the out put what you want to get

Comment: @codebyAbhishekBharti

1. I want output to select random words without any repeat words in sentence.
2. With above code which i had produced, i am receiving repeated words (Example: example example example example example1). Here i dont want 'example' should not repeat.

Comment: @codebyAbhishekBharti In brief i would like to example lets take words as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Here i would like to receive output as (1 2 3 4 5, 4 1 5 2 3, 3 6 7 8 9, 2 4 6 7 9 3, so on..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to keep track of the characters you haven't used in your set, so you don't repeat them.  Here I have a list comprehension called remaining_char:

```
def printAllKLength(set, k):
    n = len(set)
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k)

def printAllKLengthRec(set, prefix, n, k):
    if (k == 0):
        print(prefix)
        return
    remaining_char = [char for char in set if char not in prefix]
    for i in range(len(remaining_char)):
        newPrefix = prefix + remaining_char[i]
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1)
```

Comment: i am trying to add space between words, i had tried many ways and getting failed you can help me out?

Comment: @Kranthi See my second answer an upvote it if it works for you.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment, to add space between the words, you can modify your wrapper function as follows:

```
def printAllKLength(set, k):
    set = {word + "   " for word in set}
    n = len(set)
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k)
```